# xpath extract title only from link with children div

Tags: xpath, hyperlink

Here is the code

```
<a href="t1647599" title="أسعار الذهب اليوم السبت 11 أبريل 2020">
<div class="img-cont">
<img src="/im0photos/20200411/T15866049067eeb471b90336bcba2927a8e6f706027image.jpg&amp;w=200&amp;h=113&amp;q=90&amp;.jpg" alt="أسعار الذهب اليوم السبت 11 أبريل 2020">
<div class="time"><span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> منذ 3 دقيقه </div></div><div class="txt-cont"><h3>أسعار الذهب اليوم السبت 11 أبريل 2020</h3></div>
</a>
```

I want to extract only the title="أسعار الذهب اليوم السبت 11 أبريل 2020" but with its hyberlink

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your needs (select text from an "a" element with children div), use one of the expressions below :

```
//a[./div]/@title
string(//a[./div])
```